# Frida on non rooted android devices

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, reverse-engineering

How do I implement SSL unpinning on an andriod app. The app is installed on a non rooted android device. I tried rooting the phone. And when I did that, the app stops working and no longer installs when I unistalled it. I have to switch to another device which I now intend to implement SSL unpinning.

I have tried using FRIDA but met a block as it does not grant me access to the super user priviledge. I am currently using a physical device Samsung S9+ to be precise.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.